# MySQL Subquery issue in from

Tags: mysql, subquery

I wrote a query in MySQL as follows:

```
SELECT products.model, 
       price
FROM laptops 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  products.model 
            FROM products 
            WHERE products.maker = 'A' OR products.maker = 'B') 
USING (model)
```

But it did not work, there was an error occurred:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'USING (model) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

Does anybody know what's the issue in my code?

Comment: Where is the limit part? Please provide the full query `LIMIT 0, 25` is missing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is coming due to dot (.), you can try to write using `.

```
SELECT `products.model`, 
       price
FROM laptops 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  `products.model`
            FROM products 
            WHERE `products.maker` = 'A' OR `products.maker` = 'B') 
USING (model)
```